# how to add a button or link in fullcalender based on condition

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am new in Fullcalendr.I want to add a button or link in a full calender cell,if number of events in that date is greater than 3.Also when user clicks on that button I want to append a div,that will show all of my events.I had tried

```
 $(".fc-day-number").prepend("(+) ");
```

this,but it add a plus to all cells.Who will I do this
with thanks, Naeem

Comment: check $(".fc-day-number").length; it must be not 1 in your case...

Comment: I had tried this but it is not working for me.Someother suggestions please @vishal sharma

Answer (score 0):

eg. Condition. Here it sets the green color on cells which are exists event description:

---

eventRender: function (event, element) {

```
        if (event.description != null) {
            element.css('background-color', 'Green');
        }

    }
```